# How to declare a property as a subclass

Tags: typescript

I have a 3rd party lib that returns a BaseClass.

I then want to add a properties to BaseClass and use it.  But I get a compile error.

`var mySubclass : Subclass = MethodThatReturnsBaseClass();`

Compile Error:`Type Baseclass is not assignable to type Subclass`

```
interface Subclass extends BaseClass {
title: string;
}
```

How should this be written?

Comment: The issue here is that a BaseClass is not a Subclass, so it is correct in giving this compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should this be written?

## One possibility:

```
interface Subclass extends BaseClass {
    title?: string;
}
```

## Another:

```
var mySubclass : Subclass = <Subclass>MethodThatReturnsBaseClass();
```

I prefer method 1 as it is more semantically correct